# Items still showing in recyclerView after being deleting

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a recyclerview which shows data from my sqlite db. The user has an option to remove a single item or remove all items, this is meant to delete the item from the sqlite db and remove the item from the recyclerview. Deleting a single item works great.

The clear all doesn't work well. The items are deleted out the table but the recyclerview still shows the items, i'm even able to still click on them. The recyclerview is empty when i restart the activity.

```
public void updateDataSet(){
        db = new DBHandler(context);
        db.deleteUserBasket(username);
        ItemList = db.getAllItems(userName);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This is the original method I was calling for the clear all, it did work but now it's not removing the items from the recyclerView.

I've tried this too

```
public void deleteDataSet(){
        db = new DBHandler(context);
        ItemList = db.getAllUserCartItems(userName);
        int size = cartItemList.size();
        db.deleteUserBasket(userName);
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,size);
    }
```

Both methods are being called, I've stepped through them, but it seems like the notify methods aren't doing anything.

```
db.deleteUserBasket(userName);

cartItemList = db.getAllUserCartItems(userName);
basketOrderAdapter = new BasketOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cartItemList,userName);
basketOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is something else I've tried, at this point cartItemList is empty, debugging says size = 0;

This too doe's the same, where the items are still in my view

Comment: ItemList = db.getAllItems(userName);
You should update your adapter with the new list before notifying of data changes.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Check my edit out, I've added another failed attempt

Comment: If you wanna recreate the adapter this way, then after basketOrderAdapter = new BasketOrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cartItemList,userName);
set this adapter to a recyclerview.

On the other hand I would add a setter on the adapter itself for the new data. This way you do not have to recreate the adapter.

Comment: Recreating the adapter wasn't my end goal. It's just something I've tried and didn't work. I'll try a setter and see if it helps, thanks. When setting a new adapter to the RV, what happens to the old one ?

Comment: If it does not work, please share the adapter code.

Comment: I've ended up just setting the adpater to the RV as i couldn't get the setter to work, could you submit an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am curious why the setter does not work. Would you mind posting the adpter code? It is more performant to set the data in the adapter than to create a new one.

Comment: Can you update question showing `db.deleteUserBasket()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is creating new adapter with refreshed data and set it to your RecyclerView. Then the notifyDataSetChanged() is needed.

A better way would be to add a setter method in your adapter, where you set a new list. After that you should call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Gave it more thought after some time away from the PC, got the setter working. Thanks so much for your answer. Not only did you help with my problem but you taught me something new too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't delete items from the list of adapter of RecyclerView.

```
 ItemList cartItemList= db.getAllUserCartItems(userName);
```

returns a new updated list from database but it's not the one you used for adapter.

create a method to set data inside you adapter. Don't create a new adapter when you wish to update list.

```
public void setAdapterList(List<Object> newData) {
    this.data = data;
    // or clear and add new data your adapter data
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(newData);
    // You can also check out DiffUtil library to only change necessary part of your adapter
    // Change adapter as you like with notify methods
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Check my edit out, I've added another failed attempt